# sql distinct join

Tags: sql, distinct

Table:

- activities: id, userId, description, objectId
- users: id, name
- usersFriends, id, userId, friendUserId
- objects: id, name

The current query:

```
   SELECT A.*, U.*
   FROM usersFriends UF
   JOIN activities A ON A.userId = UF.friendUserId
   JOIN users U ON U.id = A.userId
   WHERE A.objectId = x
```

The problem with the current query is that if users have matching friends for example:

- user 1: tim
- user 2: ryan
- user 3: allan
- user 4: charlie

tim is friends with charlie
ryan is friends with charlie

We get the activities of object X, but we get all the activities double because tim is friends with charlie and ryan is friends with charlie, so I need some kind of distinct?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?   That query looks like it won't work in any dialect...

Comment: wooeps that was wrong, fixed!

Comment: @user1066101 - Why are you using the `UserFriends` table at all?, it looks like you don't need it. Or do you only want the activities of users that are friends with other users?

Comment: Do you only want the activities (or do you want the friends as well)?  It would help if you showed a couple of expected output rows.    If all you want is activities, you could simply use SELECT DISTINCT A.* to get distinct activities only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do like this `... AND A.userId < UF.userId`

```
SELECT A.*, U.*
   FROM usersFriends UF
   JOIN activities A ON A.userId = UF.friendUserId AND A.userId < UF.userId
   JOIN users U ON U.id = A.userId
   WHERE A.objectId = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you can do the following query (though I don't really understand the logic ):

```
SELECT A.*, U.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT friendUserId FROM usersFriends) UF
JOIN activities A ON A.userId = UF.friendUserId
JOIN users U ON U.id = A.userId
WHERE A.objectId = x
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, U.*
FROM usersFriends UF
JOIN activities A ON A.userId = UF.friendUserId
JOIN users U ON U.id = A.userId
WHERE A.objectId = x
```